# Output for logstash kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

Is there a way to process the output files into different servers? Below is for one server and if it fails how can I forward this to another server. Any hints would be appreciated. I can implement it using IF condition but since I am new to this, I did not understand what exactly to be used.

```
output {
   kafka { 
     bootstrap_servers => "kafka"
     codec => json{}
     topic_id =>  "my-topic"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple outputs in a logstash pipeline and you can filter your messages and send them to different outputs, but you cannot select one output only if the other failed.

For example, you can have two different kafka brokers in your output block.

```
output {
    kafka {
        kafka-broker-1-config
    }
    kafka {
        kafka-broker-2-config
    }
}
```

In this case, your messages will be sent to both brokers, but if one of them goes down, logstash will block all the outputs and the broker that stayed up won't get any messages.

You can solve this using a pipeline-to-pipeline communication with the [output isolator pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#output-isolator-pattern).

You would need something like this:

```
output {
    pipeline {
        send_to => [kafka1, kafka2]
    }
}
```

Then you would need two other pipelines, one for each kafka, to receive this data and send to kafka.

The output for kafka1 would be something like this:

```
input {
    pipeline {
        address => kafka1
    }
}
output {
    kafka {
        kafka-broker-1-config
    }
}
```

This way, if your kafka2 broker goes down, the kafka1 broker still gets the message, but this assumes that you want to send the message to both brokers at the same time.

If you just want to send the message to the other output in case of a failure, you can't do that with logstash alone, you will need to use a load balancer like HAProxy in front of your outputs.